# How to send local mail via postfix to another server

Tags: smtp, postfix, local

I have postfix set up for use as an STMP server to send mail for my domain, but I *receive* email for the domain via gmail/google apps. The reason I use my own postfix is because I send out a lot of transactional emails to my customers using a web app, and the volume would exceed what google allows with its SMTP servers.

Everything works fine, except cron & system mail gets routed to local users on the server, not to the appropriate accounts at google mail. How can I route this system mail to the respective google mail accounts instead?

Answer (score 3):

In this case the answer was very simple: blanking out the `mydestination` entry in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
mydestination =
```

Comment: So that server thinks it's not the destination for anything?

Comment: @NicCottrell - yes, that's my understanding, and it works so far in all my initial tests with postfix 3.3.0 on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the virutal aliases to redirect the email correctly?  I am not sure if this will do what you want to do or not.

Jay

Comment: Note sure, but I believe virtual aliases require me to enter each username and the corresponding email address individually.. I'd prefer a simpler, widespread solution if possible.